# Wacky scrolling in Chrome if you scroll from the subheader

Tags: bug, design, css

There's some goofy behaviour I've noticed in Google Chrome. Here's how to reproduce it.

## Put your cursor somewhere in this region

Or anywhere in the site's header where you can middle-click, really. Then do that: middle click to get that scrolling cursor happening, and move your cursor to scroll **left, right, or up**.

[image: The spot to place your cursor]

## This happens! Whoooaaa!

Interestingly, you can scroll *until* the point you middle-clicked on leaves the header div.

[image: The results of scrolling there]

## Some fix options

Any of these seem to work.

#### Remove #content's overflow: auto

[image: #content's overflow: auto]

#### Remove #subheader's overflow-y: hidden

[image: #subheader's overflow-y: hidden]

#### Add an overflow-x: hidden to #subheader

[image: #subheader's overflow-x: hidden]

Comment: Does this really matter?  What is the actual impact to you?

Comment: @C.Ross It matters inasmuch as CSS bugs normally do, which is not very much! If there's any reason I sound excited in my post it's because I consider this particular bug pretty neat, and not because I consider it a big deal.

Comment: This matters because it's likely that there are other CSS problems flowing from this. While it's not urgent to be fixed, when a global CSS fix rolls out, this might as well be fixed.